# Can I power my 3,5 HDD Enclosure with laptop power supply?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, power, enclosures

As stated in the title, I've got myself a nice little 3,5" HDD enclosure [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Dc0.jpg), but as of late I've lost power supply that was shipped along with it.

Can I use my 16V 3,5A laptop power supply (which is designed for IBM X40) in order to power it? Won't it damage connected hard drive?

Cheers,

Dominic

Comment: What are the power specifications of the adapter?  How many volts and Amps does draw?  Edit your question to provide this information, instead of submitting, a temporary comment.

Comment: I was asking for the specifications of the enclosure itself, or the original DC adapter, not the replacement adapter.  *I really only care about what the enclosure was designed to handle.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no, a thousand times, no!
Do not try it!

The enclosure specifies 12 VDC as shown in the picture.

Your laptop power supply is 16.5V.

1) Overvoltage will burn out the drive.

2) You might even have a 16.5V AC laptop power supply (rare, but I've seen them) since you did not specify if the laptop power supply output DC or AC.